# Equivalent to Oracle Data Masking in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, etl, privacy, sql-server-2016

I used to work with Oracle ETL/database tools and now I have transferred to a Microsoft working environment. In Oracle SQL Developer there was a feature named Data Masking which would mask selected column values with `***` characters. Is this also possible with Microsoft SQL Server 2016?

Comment: which tool are you using ?

Comment: Sorry I did not mention, I am using Microsoft sql server management studio

Comment: Are you talking about *masking*? That's a database feature that hides the data from anyone without the proper authorization. That's not "reduction"

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I believe the OP is talking about Oracle Data **Redaction**, which seems like it might be at least somewhat equivalent to [Dynamic Data Masking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/mt130841.aspx) in SQL2016+?

Comment: [Data Reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_reduction) has nothing to do with what you described. What do you actually want? SSMS is not an ETL tool. SSIS has fuzzy lookups, fuzzy matching, the database itself has data compression even in the Express edition

Comment: I used to know it as data reduction, but yes we are talking about the same thing. Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I did the proper editing.

Comment: @3N1GM4 that's not a *tool* feature, that's a database-level security feature.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos does the OP specifically require a _tool_ feature? Looks like they've edited now to clarify anyway, so I'll butt out and let you guys figure it out.

Comment: I am pretty happy with the link that explains Dynamic Data masking. Yes, it is surely a database security feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others commented, you are probably looking for [Dynamic Data Masking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt130841.aspx) which is available in [all versions of SQL Server 2016 SP1](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/11/sql-server-2016/big-deal-sp1), even Express and the embedded LocalDB. The equivalent in Oracle is [Data Redaction](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ASOAG/redaction.htm#ASOAG594)

You'll find a nice overview in [Use Dynamic Data Masking to obfuscate your sensitive data](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2016/01/25/use-dynamic-data-masking-to-obfuscate-your-sensitive-data/)